# descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, django

Trying to combine date & time and received error:

`descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'datetime.date'`

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta

instance = Model.objects.get(pk=id)

datetime = datetime.combine(datetime.date(instance.mydate), datetime.time(instance.mytime))
```

Edit:

mydate and mytime are stored here:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    mydate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    mytime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Edit 2:

I did have this in place but was looking for a 1 line solution:

```
mydate = datetime.strptime(str(instance.mydate), '%Y-%m-%d')        
mytime = datetime.strptime(str(instance.mytime), '%H:%M:%S')        
datetime = datetime.combine(datetime.date(mydate), datetime.time(mytime))
```

Comment: What is `instance.mydate` ? and what is `isntance.mytime` ?

Comment: `instance.mydate` is date stored in my model/table in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Same for time stored as `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Posted an answer please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are actually trying to call `datetime.datetime.date()` , you should be calling `datetime.date()`. I am guessing you need to use `datetime.time()` instead of `datetime.datetime.time()` also.

Also, according to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) , the parameters to `datetime.date()` are three integers indicating the year, month and day of the date.

You should do -

```
datetime = datetime.combine(date(instance.mydate.year, instance.mydate.month, instance.mydate.day), time(instance.mytime.hour, instance.mytime.minute, instance.mytime.second))
```

Give the time, upto the accuracy you want, As an example I gave till `second` , documentation for that is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time).

Comment: Thank you, it is working. I did have another way of doing it in place using `.strptime` but it was three lines as the date and time were first converted to string unsing `.strptime` and then combined. FYI I did post my original solution in my OP.